# How is default parameter value T() interpreted in a template?

Tags: c++, templates, initialization

I came across this code and I want to know how is `T()` interpreted with different datatypes?

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {

    T _val;
    std::string _message;


    // constructor
    MyClass(std::string const &msg, T defaultVal = T())
    : _val(defaultVal), _message(msg)
   {
        // some code that will use msg and defaultVal
   }


}
```

Comment: It just calls the unargumented constructor of whatever type it's passed.

Comment: Replace `T` with some datatypes and you will see how it is interpreted. E.g. for `int` it will be `MyClass(std::string const &msg, int defaultVal = int())`

Answer (score 0):

`T()` is an example of [*value initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). And it does behave differently depending on what `T` is exactly. The immediate categories are as follows:

> The effects of value initialization are:
>
> 1. if T is a class type with no default constructor or with a user-provided or deleted default constructor, the object is [*default-initialized*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization);
> 2. if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is [*zero-initialized*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) and then it is *default-initialized* if it has a non-trivial default constructor;
> 3. if T is an array type, each element of the array is *value-initialized*;
> 4. otherwise, the object is *zero-initialized*.

"default initialization" and "zero initialization" are themselves terms with an exact meaning that must be determined for the exact type being used. Ultimately, initialization in C++ is a bit of a rabbit hole. I trust there is no need to explain what "zero-initialize" means, it's just setting the value of the object to an appropriate zero. As for "default initialization", it's defined as follows:

> The effects of default initialization are:
>
> - if T is class type, the constructors are considered and subjected to overload resolution against the empty argument list. The constructor selected (which is one of the default constructors) is called to provide the initial value for the new object;
> - if T is an array type, every element of the array is default-initialized;
> - otherwise, nothing is done: the objects with automatic storage duration (and their subobjects) are initialized to indeterminate values.

Now, to name a couple of examples:

1. `int()` - Following the list items above, we initialize an `int` to be `0`.
2. `std::string()` - This calls the default constructor of `std::string`, producing an empty string.